# How Add fake row in Grid helper Telerik to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I need to add a line in the thead of table that going contenter inputs and selects that are used as parameters for filtering.
It is more or less how I wanted to stay:

```
<table>
      <thead>
           <tr>
               <th> Name </ th> ...
               <th> Type </ th>
           </tr>
           <tr> <!-- this is the 'tr fake' in thead -->
               <th> <input type="text"/> </ th>
               <th> <select name="nb"> ...</ select> </ th>
           <tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> .....
</table>
```

How do I add the this tr in table using the helper telerik grid for ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Telerik ASP.NET MVC 2010 Q3 Beta](http://www.telerik.com/community/labs/telerik-extensions-for-asp-net-mvc-1635398404.aspx) has Custom Toolbar template functionality implemented. An example can be seen in [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc-beta/grid/customtoolbar) which actually does implement pretty much what you want.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for!
You know when will come the downloadable version in codeplex ?